# What measurement units does Silverlight and WPF use?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, units-of-measurement

Does anyone know what measurement units are used by Silverlight/WFP? For example, if I create a new button and set its height to 150, is that 150 pixels? points? millimeters?

I design all of my applications in Adobe Illustrator before proceeding to code, and although I try and set everything to the dimensions in my Illustrator file, the Silverlight application is usually larger.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

MSDN's documentation states that the [`FrameworkElement.Height`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/ms600880(v=vs.95)) property (for Silverlight) refers to:

> The height, in pixels, of the object

However, [for WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.height?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_FrameworkElement_Height) it refers to:

> a device-independent unit (1/96th inch) measurement

So, to answer your question... **pixels** for Silverlight, **device-independent units** for WPF.

Comment: Not pixles. Device Independent Units.

Comment: I'm going to have to play around with my settings in Illustrator. I've been using pixels for everything but text. Here's some more information regarding WPF vs Silverlight http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903925(VS.95).aspx

Comment: FYI: Microsoft uses 96 ppi. Adobe Illustrator uses 72 ppi.

Answer (score 30):

Although in *theory*, 1 unit in WPF is 1/96th of an inch, that's frequently not the case in practice.

It's usually true when printing. But it's rarely true on screen. The reason for this is that Windows almost always knows the true resolution of a printer, but almost never knows the true resolution of a screen.

For example, I have three screens attached to my computer. Windows thinks that they all have a resolution of 96 pixels per inch. Actually they don't. Two of them have a resolution of 101 pixels per inch, and one has a resolution of 94 pixels per inch. (Why? Because Windows has no way of working the true  resolutions out for itself, and I haven't told it. The fiction that they all have the same pixel size is close to the truth, and turns out to be a convenient fiction.)

So when I create, say, a Rectangle in WPF with Width and Height both set to 96, the size of the Rectangle actually depends on which screen it appears on. Windows thinks that all 3 screens have a resolution of 96 pixels per inch, and so it'll render the rectangle as being 96 pixels tall and wide no matter which screen it appears on. That'll make it appear 0.95 inches tall on two of the screens, and 1.02 inches tall on the third.

So in practice, that means that units in WPF on my computer here are either 1/100th of an inch, or 1/94th of an inch in practice. (I.e., in practice, the size of 1 unit in WPF is exactly the size of 1 pixel on my particular setup, no matter how big the pixels happen to be.)

I could change that. I could reconfigure Windows - I could tell it the actual resolution of all 3 screens, in which case the nominal and actual WPF unit sizes would coincide. Or I could lie - I could claim that I have 200 pixel per inch screens, in which case everything would be massive...

The basic problem here is that there is no standard way for the computer to discover the true size of the physical pixels on the screen, and very few people bother to set it up by hand. (And in fact you can cause problems by configuring it 'correctly', because a lot of software doesn't behave correctly when you do.) So the majority of Windows computers don't report physical pixel sizes correctly to WPF - they can't because they don't know.

Consequently, there's no reliable answer to the question - 1 unit in WPF could be pretty much anything on screen. (In practice, most of the time, it turns out to be 1 pixel, simply because if you don't tell Windows anything else, it defaults to assuming that your screens have pixels that are 1/96th of an inch tall, which is the same as 1 WPF unit. And for most desktop screens, that's actually quite likely to be a good guess. But this isn't universal. On systems configured with what used to be called 'large fonts' for example, you'll find a different nominal screen resolution, and 1 WPF unit will correspond to slightly more than 1 physical pixel - about 1.2 in fact.)

With printers, it's all much more predictable. Printers are invariably able to report their resolutions correctly. So if you print something that's 96 WPF units high, you can be confident that it will be 1 inch high.

Comment: Good description. I've got a dual-display hookup with a laptop. The laptop is a Vaio VPCF2 with 134 physical pixels per inch. The external monitor is an HP 2310m with 95.7 ppi. If I set a Label width to 96, it shows up as 1.25" on the HP. If I set it to 134, it shows up as 1.25" on the Vaio. So I have to scale my expected ppi by 0.8 to get it to show up as exactly 1" on my monitor. And that depends on which monitor I expect it to display on. But actually, I don't *really* care, so I'm going with 96 after all as "close enough".

Answer (score 2):

The documentation refers to Pixels, however these are Pixels where there are 96 such pixels per inch.   A line of Width 96 when display on a 120 DPI display will be 120 actual device pixels.  Similarly such a line drawn on a printer output which has 600 DPI will be 600 pixels long.

Answer (score 1):

They are **Device Independent Units**.

You can find more detailed explanations [here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43520/Device-Independent-Units-to-Points-to-Inches.aspx)